# How to get out of a tag-back scenario

Tags: office

not 100% sure this is on-topic, if not I apologize...

My workplace organizes a summer weekly Friday happy hour, and whoever gets to organize it picks the person to organize it next.

My friend and I have gotten into this pattern of each picking the other, after I was picked for organizing the first meeting, picked him and he tagged me back.

This has been going on for almost a month now, and I tried getting out of it by invoking the no tag back rule.

He replied like this (touché):

> [I will go ahead and invoke the "no anti-no tags-back" rule, stamp it
>   and call no erasies. Touch blue, make it true.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aflyz9IFoZE)

How should I reply? Can you help me be the one to [drop the mic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pItugbXjrYc) on this one? :)

Comment: Interesting conundrum, but these types of interpersonal skills aren't really within the spirit of this site.

Comment: @RobertCartaino - Thanks for your feedback Robert, and sorry for posting here! I have to say though, that the `office` tag is a bit confusing, as its description (`Hacks related to the office such as dealing with people or situations.`) seemed to match well with the spirit of the question, and that's what made me ultimately post.

Answer (score 5):

Just don't pick him next time. Pick someone else, and perhaps even point out to the person you pick that it would be good to see the duties rotate throughout the group.

Yes, you run the risk that if anyone in the future chooses him, he might then choose you. But you just go choose someone else (not the person who chose him) in the hope of getting the chains that lead to you to keep getting longer and longer.